# FileSystemWatcher Waiting

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

The following process remains waiting, while the file is present. 
I probably made ​​an error, but I don't see where.

```
System.IO.WaitForChangedResult result;
seeTransFile.WaitForChanged(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created);
string seeDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(SynDir, fileName + @".md5");
result = watcher.WaitForChanged(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: which line program wait? what is `seeTransFile`?

Comment: It's a "FileSystemWatcehr" Composent add to my form

Comment: Why do you provide the lines "seeTransFile.WaitForChanged" and "string seeDirectory ="? How are they relevant for the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileSystemWatcher will only trigger when the file is created/changed. Existing files are ignored.

First start your FileSystemWatcher, then use Directory.GetFiles to get existing files.

If you need to read the contents of files detected by FileSystemWatcher, I recommend you verify that the owner of the file has released all locks on it by using this code:

```
try 
{
    // Attempts to open then close the file in RW mode, denying other users to place any locks.
    FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    fs.Close();
    fileClosed = true; // success
}
catch (IOException) {}
```

If a lock is present on the file, either wait for it to be released by its owner or put the file on a queue and retry later.

Comment: exactly, more or less that code worked for me for a long time, just put files into the queue and check periodically if they are finished, however, bear in mind that you can loose some filesystem changes if system goes down, so could be useful to mark already processed files somehow

Comment: I move my files to a subdirectory after they have been processed, and archive/delete them after a number of days. This allows me to resend a batch of files using drag and drop in Windows Explorer.

Comment: well, thats a good option, however, if you register a file as changed after FileWatcher evet fires, but it is still locked at the moment your system dies, you'll loose the track of it easily, since you cannot move it until its finished and the only pointer to it is your queue in memory

Comment: I put all files on a queue in memory, and have a separate thread that fires an event when all locks are released (or move them back to the end of the queue if order is not important). If I lose the queue, the files are picked up later using GetFiles and put back on the queue.

Comment: ok, right, if yoiu move all the files outside the directory after they are unlocked, that would totally work :) I decided to recheck my files against db etc. after the system failure.

Answer (score 0):

since you already added FileSystemWatcher component configure it to watch as below. remove other code lines

```
System.IO.WaitForChangedResult result;
seeTransFile.Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
seeTransFile.Filter = fileName + @".md5";
result = seeTransFile.WaitForChanged(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created);
```